# How to create an array from user input in Java and perform operations on in

Tags: java, arrays

I have just started learning Java, and i can't figure out how to create an array from user input. For example, a user inputs n numbers, and the program outputs the square of each number. Wherever I look, i see that the array length is predefined, and I can't seem to find any comprehensible explanation on how to have it depend on the amount of input values from the user.

Comment: For beginner, try to use array. That is right that the array length must defined first. So try define the length 1000. Or for advanced level, you can try to use ArrayList. You have to go through about arraylist before you try on it. With arraylist, you not need to define the size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an **arraylist** or a **list** of integers instead, so that you can add items to the list as and when required. Also, the list would then have only as many elements as the number of inputs.

**Syntax**:

```
List<Integer> elements = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

To *add* elements to the list, use:

```
elements.add(new_item);
```

To *access* members of the list, use:

```
elements.get(index);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ask user that how many number he wants to enter and define array of that much size .
this is the only way that you can go with if you are new in java.

else you can use ArrayList. for that see COLLECTIONS IN JAVA

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `ArrayList` instead of an array. It has no predefined size and scales with the amount of inputs.

```
List<Integer> inputs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
inputs.add(yourNumber);
inputs.get(index);
```

Link to the JavaDoc: [ArrayList API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use java.util.ArrayList instead, it would solve your problem. For your reference http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html